# KendoUI Upload Files Data Attribute

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've created a grid with a custom popup edit window.  In the template I'm using data attributes to give values to the appropriate inputs.  For example:

```
<input id="cgrid-edit-contact" name="contact" tabindex="3" data-bind="value: contact.contactid" style="width:214px" />`
```

The problem I'm having is I have a KendoUpload widget where I want to show the file that has been previously uploaded.  The following page says that to configure widgets you provide `data-` followed by the Kendo attribute name.  So to set the files attribute would look like this:

```
<input id="cgrid-edit-file" type="file" data-files="[{name: 'file1.doc', size: 525, extension: '.doc'}]" style="width:214px;display:inline" />
```

Obviously the content should be dynamic, but I cannot even get static values to initialize.  Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
  <input id="cgrid-edit-file" 
         type="file" 
         data-files="[{name: 'file1.doc', size: 525, extension: '.doc'}]" 
         data-role="upload" 
         data-async="{ saveUrl: 'save' }"
  />
```

However you currently cannot use MVVM to specify the files which the upload can display. You can only specify them as a data attribute.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime MVVM is supported:

HTML:

```
<!-- .. -->
data-files="[ viewModel.GetCurrentFilename() ]"
<!-- .. -->
```

JS:

```
//.. viewModel ..
GetCurrentFilename: function ()
{
    return {name: 'file1.doc', size: 525, extension: '.doc'};
}
//..
```